# Where to handle the parent window state from a user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a MainWindowView with my TitleBarView user control on it:

```
<Grid>
    <local:TitleBarView DataContext="{Binding TitleBarViewModel}"/>
</Grid>
```

With it's MainWindowViewModel:

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    TitleBarViewModel = new TitleBarViewModel(Minimize, Maximize, Close);
}

public void Close() {...}

public void Minimize() {...}

public WindowState Maximize() {...}
```

And a TitleBarView with some buttons that bind to the commands in TitleBarViewModel:

```
public ICommand MinimizeCommand { get; set; }
public ICommand MaximizeCommand { get; set; }
public ICommand CloseCommand { get; set; }

WindowState _windowState;

public TitleBarViewModel(Action minimize , Func<WindowState> maximize , Action close)
{
    MinimizeCommand = new MinimizeCommand(minimize);
    MaximizeCommand = new MaximizeCommand(this, maximize);
    CloseCommand = new CloseCommand(close);
}
```

As you can see for the 3 buttons on my title bar, I pass 3 callback functions from my MainWindowViewModel to my TitleBarViewModel Which each then gets turned into commands and is then bound to with buttons.
Now as far as I understand this is proper MVVM. My problem is if I want to implement dragging the title bar to drag the window or double click the title bar to maximize the window, the amount of callback functions I have to pass to the TitleBarViewModel, and the amount of command classes I have to make goes up for every single event.
Am I handling the propagation of events and encapsulation of the main view's functions right? Would it be ok to just pass the main window to the title bar and just do with it as I please? I know you can but should you.
I want to keep the main window clean as I also want to place a nav bar on it and then a user control that will act as a viewport that changes windows when I use the user control.

Comment: If I were you, I don't think it is necessary to separate VM for titile bar and VM for window because title bar is essential part of window and the relationship between window and its title bar is completely fixed. Furthermore, in my view, minimize, maximize and close window functions are purely for controlling the window and such functions should be handled within V rather than in VM.

Comment: You must implement the Window behavior in the code-behind. If you want to use commands then implement a RoutedCommand in the Window. Then use this command to bind it to the buttons in your TitlebarView. This kind of logic does not belong to the view model.

Comment: Oh wow this makes so much more sense. I was wondering what the code behind was for. Sounds weird, but everyone I've seen so far avoids it. But now I understand that viewmodel isn't just a place for all code to land but that layer between the model and view. Ive heard it before it just never clicked.